# Build HMM of text data in R

Tags: r, text, nlp, tagging, hidden-markov-models

I'm trying to make my own HMM tagging in R but don't know how to estimate parameter values since the packages I have been working with haven't worked with my data. The latest package I have been trying to work with is HiddenMarkov. I have 2 issues I need to solve:

1. The package wants me to input a vector of observations, but in my case every observation is a vector (vector of words). Is there another package more suitable for my goal than HiddenMarkov-package? Or can it be solved with lists or is there another way?
2. The package also needs a specific distribution. I'm working with nominal data, what distribution is going to be specified?

Comment: While this is technically an R question, I kind of suspect that you are much more likely to get an answer on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). I kind of feel that people over there have much more experience with implementing procedures when your observations are vectors themselves, and also with specifying distributions. Edit: That being said, maybe someone else here also knows the answer.